# Domino agent - Remote server is not a known TCP/IP host

Tags: lotus-domino, server-administration

I have a Domino development server I can't get web-based emails to send from.  The error I'm getting is "The remote server is not a known TCP/IP host". The server works fine for Notes based emails, but I'm generating emails from LotusScript in an app, and they are not sending. 
This server was recently created (Dom 8.5.3).

I have the server sending email directly to the Internet on all location documents (for Notes client).

Comment: I edited the title to make it clear that this issue affects a Domino agent. It probably really is a Domino Administration issue, which would ordinarily belong on ServerFault instead of StackOverflow; but developers run into this problem a lot on test server so I'm not flagging it.

Comment: If the answer and comments below haven't resolved the issue, I suggest that you enter the following command on your server console and paste the output into the question to give us further detail:  "trace TCPIP!!!NB1/NOTEbookS"

Answer (score 1):

See IBM Technote #[1099632](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21099632) "Notes/Domino background agent fails to send mail; Errors may occur in logs":

> These errors may be caused by an improper entry for the Mail Server field in the Server document in the Domino Directory (public Name and Address Book).
>
> The errors may also be caused by a server configuration or TCPIP issue. For example, if the Network Address field for a TCPIP port contains either an incorrect host name or an IP address, the errors occur. If the DNS is not working correctly the errors will occur.
>
> The issue was noted in at least one case because the server was resolvable by IP address but not resolvable by Fully Qualified Host Name (FQHN). The IP address was listed in the Net Address field of the Server document but this error message still appeared. To resolve this issue, update the DNS servers to point the FQHN to the correct server. In one case it was discovered that the particular Domino server was not listed in its own host table. Update the host file of the server with the FQHN pointing to its own IP or localhost address.

The Technote also provides steps to troubleshoot the issue.

Also, you can enable some debugging to determine where the problem surfaces.

> For outbound SMTP-related issues, enable the debug parameters below on the server to capture data:
>   CONSOLE_LOG_ENABLED=1
>   DEBUG_THREADID=1
>   debug_show_timeout=1
>   debug_capture_timeout=1
>   SMTPClientDebug=1

See [Collecting data for Domino SMTP mail routing issues](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21454020) for more details on that

Comment: Mailserver field has 'CN=NB1/O=NOTEbookS' which is the server's name. Netaddresses field has three entries..the DNS of the machine (Comccast's DNS setting), the machine (title is E6400), and 127.0.0.1 (the machine). There is no setting for a default SMTP port...should there be? I'm thinking there is somewhere in the server document where you identify that the server is used for DNS, (instead of using Comcst's DNS server) but I can't find out where it is.

Comment: The remark abot the Network Address is referring to the table on the Notes Network Ports sub-tab of the Ports tab in the server document.  The column labeled Net Address should have the fully qualified name (e.g., server1@mydomain.com) or the IP address of the server.  I have sometimes seen this exact problem when (a) the host name is entered instead of the fully qualified name and (b) the network configuration on the server is not set up to append the domain suffix automatically.

Comment: Richard, from what it looks like, that is a dev server installed on a Laptop, not a server ;)

Comment: If it's all self-contained within a laptop, then localhost or 127.0.0.1 is the best solution.  The entries in the NetAddresses field are compiled from the Ports table.  From the information Beau provided, we can't tell if it's correct because we don't know which entry corresponds to the TCPIP port.

Comment: Hallelujah!  The problem was that the TCPIP server (that did the DNS lookup) was set as the comcast server. The development Domino server, which is not broadcasting an IP address is not known to that DNS, so it was faiiling. I changed the TCPIP Post net address to 127.0.0.1 and it works fine.  The trace was a Godsend. Many thanks to you all!

Comment: So please accept this answer as the correct one, so we can easily see the issue has been solved.